# Canvas for() loop, lineTo() and closePath()

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I need to create a for loop to make floated skewed image canvas drawings. First drawing is okay, but other drawing are starting from where older drawing ends. I'm using clearPath() to clear old coordinates but it's not working.

Here is my code :

```
function draw(){
    var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
    var $width = $('#canvas').parent().width();
    var $canvas_width = 380;
    var $canvas_margin = 15;
    var $canvas_height = 810;

    var $total_draw = $width / Math.ceil($canvas_width);
    var $start = 0;


    for(var $i = 1; $i <= 2; $i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo($start,0);
        ctx.lineTo($canvas_width,0);
        ctx.lineTo($start,$canvas_height);
        ctx.lineTo(Math.abs($canvas_width) * -1,$canvas_height);
        ctx.lineTo($start,0);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();


        $start += ($canvas_width + $canvas_margin);
    }       
}
```

**Edit**

Ok my mistake. I had made a calculation mistake. After a few control hours, i have corrected calculations.

This sample is working.

```
function draw(){
    var ctx = $('#canvas')[0].getContext('2d');
    var $width = $('#canvas').parent().width();
    var $canvas_width = 380;
    var $canvas_margin = 20;
    var $canvas_height = 810;

    var $total_draw = $width / Math.ceil($canvas_width);
    var $start = 0;

    for(var i = 1; i <= $total_draw + 1; i++){
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo($start,0);
        ctx.lineTo($start + $canvas_width,0);
        ctx.lineTo($start, $canvas_height);
        ctx.lineTo(-380 + $start, $canvas_height);
        ctx.lineTo($start,0);
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();

        $start = $start + ($canvas_width + $canvas_margin);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

`closePath` will just line the last point to the first one so you don't need to do `ctx.lineTo($start,0);`, just put `ctx.closePath();` before `ctx.stroke();`.

Moreover, I think everything is okay with the canvas, (the `beginPath` prevent lining last point to new one, and on top of that you use moveTo which move the current point without lining) but your code is not. I don't know what you are trying to do (maybe you should explain it ?) but you start from a point at the top, then line at the top-right corner (so every first lines will overlay), etc.

Comment: If you don't want to use border that's right. But if you will, you have to write the last coords.

Comment: If a talk about my first sentence and by border you mean use `stroke`, no: that's the usefullness of [`closepath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Canvas/Tutorial/Drawing_shapes#Drawing_paths).

Comment: Moreover, to avoid writing `+$start`, you can use `translate` (but don't forget to `save` then `restore`). See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jFwqq/) for a demo. Is your code now doing what you want ? Otherwise, what is wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `context.save()` at the start inside the `for` loop `conxtext.restore()` at the end.
This way, positions applied between these 2 calls will affect only the current rendering.

Comment: Is this working with createPattern method? Cause i tried but failed.